# Is there a nice way to move .txt files with a specific character in the file (not filename) to another directory?

Tags: bash, macos

Using bash on Mac, I'm trying check a folder of .txt files and, any file that has a bullet character (•) *anywhere* in it,  move those .txt files to a new folder/subdirectory. Any suggestions?

Comment: `mv *•*.txt newdir` should work

Comment: @jordanm That looks for `•` in the file name, not the file contents.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` can be used for checking for character presence in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ./a/*.txt; do
    if grep -q • "$filename"; then
        mv "$filename" ./b/
    fi
done
```

Comment: `$filename` should be quoted, else this breaks for filenames with blanks or shell metacharacters in them.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no spaces in the .txt filenames (thanks @jordanm, for pointing that
out), you can do it in one line - you can use grep to tell you the filenames
(`-l`) containing a pattern (`-e`) and move them to your new_directory:

```
mv $(grep -l old_directory/*.txt -e •) new_directory/
```

Comment: This won't work if any of the file names contain a space.

Comment: Awesome! For filenames with spaces: `mv "$(grep -l old_directory/*.txt -e •)" new_directory/`

Comment: @Andrey Moiseev, putting double quotes around the `$( ... )` part of the command doesn't work for me... but I'm having trouble understanding the reason for the error I get.

Comment: The quotes in `mv "$(grep -l old_directory/*.txt -e •)" new_directory/` will work as designed, when only 1 file is found and that file has a space in its name. When `grep` returns 2 files, the paths/filenames are joined and the command with the quotes will try to move 1 file with a name like `"old_directory/firstfile.txt old_directory/secondfile.txt"`. It will look for a subdirectory with a space in it: `firstfile.txt old_directory`. I don't think  `secondfile.txt` will be found in that directory.

Comment: @WalterA, yes now I see that this is the behaviour I observed when I tested it out. Thanks